# Android : send JSON with HttpURLConnection using OutputStream

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I'm trying to send a JSON object with my HttpURLConnection. I followed tutorials and I don't understand why my code doesn't work. The HttpURLConnection works but when I debug my program it contains no json.

I call the doInBackground here:

```
public void clickbuttonRecieve(View v) {
    MyAsync performBackgroundTask = new MyAsync();
    performBackgroundTask.execute();
}
```

this is the AsyncTask function :

```
 private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String LOGIN_URL = "http://bomatec.be/webservice2.php";

        DataOutputStream wr;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url;

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... tmps) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(LOGIN_URL);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true); //moved here
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                //conn.connect();

                //conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                //conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

                data.put("user", "12");
                data.put("lat", "50.8");
                data.put("lng", "4.3");

                String json = data.toString();

                OutputStream wr = conn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(wr, "UTF-8");
                osw.write(json);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("MYAPP", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("MYAPP", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }

            //conn.disconnect();

            return null;



        }


    }
```

When I debug my code these are the values:

[IMG]http://i63.tinypic.com/1192iwg.png[/IMG]

logcat :

```
12-26 17:27:17.556 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
12-26 17:27:17.556 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
12-26 17:27:17.556 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18095: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
12-26 17:27:17.566 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-26 17:27:17.566 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
12-26 17:27:17.566 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18099: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
12-26 17:27:17.566 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
12-26 17:27:18.207 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
12-26 17:27:18.207 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17991: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
12-26 17:27:18.207 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
12-26 17:27:18.217 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-26 17:27:18.217 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 497: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-26 17:27:18.227 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-26 17:27:18.227 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-26 17:27:18.227 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 519: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-26 17:27:18.227 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-26 17:27:18.387 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
12-26 17:27:18.387 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18614: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
12-26 17:27:18.387 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
12-26 17:27:18.387 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
12-26 17:27:18.387 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 18614: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
12-26 17:27:18.387 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
12-26 17:27:18.797 10192-10194/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 216K, 12% free 9585K/10887K, paused 16ms+32ms, total 222ms
12-26 17:27:19.358 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
12-26 17:27:19.358 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 190: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
12-26 17:27:19.358 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
12-26 17:27:19.358 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
12-26 17:27:19.358 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instance field 16
12-26 17:27:19.358 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e7
12-26 17:27:19.748 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzah
12-26 17:27:19.748 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 230 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
12-26 17:27:19.748 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000c
12-26 17:27:19.748 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
12-26 17:27:19.748 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
12-26 17:27:19.748 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
12-26 17:27:19.878 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzj
12-26 17:27:19.878 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 421: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
12-26 17:27:19.878 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
12-26 17:27:23.872 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-26 17:27:23.952 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-26 17:27:23.952 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-26 17:27:25.434 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-26 17:27:25.464 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/Choreographer: Skipped 172 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-26 17:27:28.116 10192-10192/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven I/Choreographer: Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-26 17:27:38.867 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: Connection already established
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:666)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:222)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven.MainActivity$MyAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:197)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-26 17:27:38.917 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-26 17:27:38.947 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-26 17:27:38.957 10192-10722/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: `conn.connect();`. Remove that.

Comment: What is very wron in your code that you just continue with the code after a catch. You should stop then and log errormessages and/or display the errormeaages in onPostExecute(). .Also you should add e.PrintStackTrace() commands in the catch blocks and use e.getMessage() to see what is the reason.

Comment: @greenapps : or put everything in one try? and catch it all later?

Comment: Do as you want. But if you put all in one block it's more difficult to see when things go wrong.

Comment: @greenapps : when i remove .connect() there is no connection..

Comment: You should tell which catch is invoked then and what e.getMessage() is. And e.printStackTrace)'.

Comment: Add `conn.setDoInput(true); ` And show your adapted code.

Comment: @greenapps : I adapted my code; I have no errors but also no data in my data. I added a pic of my debugger data;

Comment: You still continue with your code when there is a catch. You have not everywhere an e.printStackTrace(). You are not using e.getMessage().  You did not post the LogCat here. It this way it does not make sense trying to help you.

Comment: And add an onPostExecute() where you display errors to the user.

Comment: @greenapps I edited the code. I'm not sure how to write the onPostExecute... It's a problem with my connection is given in logcat. But will that cause the problem I have that there is no data send?

Comment: 'e.getMessage();'. That does nothing.  'Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected IOExceptionn", e);'. And that should be  Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected IOExceptionn: ", e.getMessage());. And you still continue with your code when there is a catch. You should put an 'return;' at the end of every catch. You should post more of the logcat (after having edited your code and a new run.).

Comment: I edited the original question. The debugger goes almost in every catch.. I hope your more with this logcat..

Comment: `The debugger goes almost in every catch.`. That is impossible as you return in a catch.

Comment: Sorry, that reply was older than the code now. Exception is java.net.ProtocolException: Connection already established.

Comment: `java.net.ProtocolException: Connection already established
12-26 16:57:16.044 10613-11182/com.example.stevengerrits.bomatec_gerrits_steven W/System.err:     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:666)`. So you have a ProtocolException as you can establish a connection only once in the http protocol. Please show your complete AsyncTask class. Also show how you call your asynctask. As otherwise i cannot see why there would be a second connection attempt. Or dit you add another `conn.connect()` somewhere.?

Comment: @greenapps : I updated everything. Thanks for your help! I appreciate it

Comment: Your code does not produce any errors at me. I added code to read the produced page and received `test1{"posts":[1]}test`.

Comment: Reboot your device. Reboot your pc and try again.

Comment: @greenapps : Yes but how can i read the json? The Json is not passed, or is it?

Comment: I also get the" test1{"posts":[1]}test" but never the json

Comment: That is json! Which json are you talking about? How is it posible that you can read the page too where you are only telling that you have exceptions?

Comment: I mean the json location data. The data i create with "JSONObject data = new JSONObject(); data.put("user", "12");....

Comment: Please answer ALL my questions and remarks! And where would you wanna get that json then?

Comment: @greenapps I want to send the json with my http POST. So i can receive and read it in the webservice. There is only the "java.net.ProtocolException: Connection already established " error but that's not the problem I think. Maybe I send the json already but doesn't handle it correctly. Thank you for your good help, sorry for my questions